# Extract decimal or Integer from a string in php

Tags: php

Eg:

```
$str .= "Additional tax(2.34)";
$str .= "Additional tax(3)";
```

Can anyone help me up to extract the number from the string. I need an array format like this

```
Array ( [0] => 2.34 [1] => 3 );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<?php
    $str = '';
    $str .= "Additional tax(2.34)";
    $str .= "Additional tax(3)";

    if (preg_match_all('/\((\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\)/', $str, $matches) > 0) {
        var_dump($matches[1]);
    }
?>
```