# extracting numbers from string in php

Tags: php, data-extraction

I'm wondering how to extract numbers from a string for example

```
$string = "1.8 to 250"
```

What i want to get is,

```
$a = 1.8
$b = 250
```

Thanks for any help provided

Comment: This is for decimal numbers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687284/extract-decimal-or-integer-from-a-string-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$str = '1.8 to 250';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

From this post [Extract numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string)

Comment: I was able to find the answer from the link you provided thanks!

Comment: Consider using this expression '/\d+/' since "/" is the standard regex delimiter, and using other delimiters only adds confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $str = '1.8 to 250';
   $string = explode(" ",$str);
   //print_r($string);
  for($i = 0;$i < count($string);$i++){
     if(is_numeric($string[$i])){
        print "\n $string[$i]";
     }  
  }
```